# Continuous function inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

We have $f:R\to R$ continuous and $\forall b \in R$, $\exists (a_n)$ strictly decreasing with the limit $b$, such that $|f(a_n) - f(b)|\le a_n - b$

Prove that $|f(x) - f(y)|\le|x - y|, \forall x,y \in R$

Can someone help me? I want just some hints.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this claim is true !

Think about a locally lipschitz  function which is not globally lipschitz .